# Launch application on web server

Tags: cgi

If I wanted to use a CGI script to launch an application on a machine running a web server, how would I do so?  For instance, I want to run a command line audio player when a link is clicked.  I was able to setup a simple cgi script that launches mplayer, but it only shows output in the browser, no actual audio playing on host machine.

Comment: Do you understand the security implications of this?

Answer (score 0):

// Edit: Now I understand, what you are trying to do. In php it would be something as:

```
system("mplayer /tmp/yourfile.mp3 &");
```

The function in perl [should be quite similar](http://www.perlhowto.com/executing_external_commands).

Comment: Oh.  This is for audio, not video.  Basically when a link is clicked, a wav file is played on the web server machine.

Comment: ok, but this will not work either. That's why every audio/video page needs aditional plugins (or html5 audio/video).

Comment: I want to execute mplayer on the web server, to play music on that machine, not the machine that the link is clicked from.

Comment: Sorry, as a simple example. You want to play „there is a visitor“ on your host as a client connects to the webserver?

Comment: I want to play the audio file on the server itself.  The only thing I want to do with the local machine (client) is click a link.  After that, music plays on the server.